# FILTER statement in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have the following postgreSQL query (a simple example of users and their messages linked through user id):

```sql
SELECT users.id, 
COUNT(messages.id) as "user_messages", 
COUNT(messages.id) FILTER (WHERE messages.status='sent') as "sent_messages"
FROM users
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.user_id=users.id 
GROUP BY users.id;
```

This query runs fine in psql, but I have no idea how to add the `FILTER` statement in my code using [Typeorm's querybuilder](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder) and docs are not helping much.

Currently, my approach is something like:

```
queryBuilder.select('users.id', 'user_id')
.addSelect('COUNT(messages.id)', 'user_messages')
.addSelect('COUNT(messages.id)', 'sent_messages') // <- Add magic filter here?
.from('users', 'users')
.leftJoin('messages', 'messages', 'users.id = messages.users_id')
.groupBy('users.id')
```

I'm trying to avoid using a subquery in each select if possible as the `FILTER` approach in the first code seems way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of these should work:

```
.addSelect('COUNT(messages.id) FILTER (WHERE messages.status = 'sent')', 'user_messages')

.addSelect('COUNT( (messages.status = 'sent')::int )', 'user_messages')

.addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN messages.status = 'sent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)', 'user_messages')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a feasible workaround by adding the whole filter to the select string:

```
queryBuilder.select('users.id', 'user_id')
.addSelect('COUNT(messages.id)', 'user_messages')
.addSelect(`COUNT(messages.id) FILTER (WHERE messages.status='sent')`, 'sent_messages')
.from('users', 'users')
.leftJoin('messages', 'messages', 'users.id = messages.users_id')
.groupBy('users.id')
```

It is far from ideal as the whole filter is injected as a string and I cannot use any of the parameters utilities from TypeORM.
I'm not sure if there is a better solution.